# how do I set the source tray (InputBin) per page when using System.Printing to print?

Tags: system.printing

I am trying to print a document using classes in the System.Printing .NET namespace.  I have tried using PrintDialog.PrintDocument on a DocumentPaginator and building an XPS file and then using Queue.AddJob to send it, but I can't seem to find a way to select a different source tray / input bin for different pages within the document.  I can do it for the whole document using the PrintTicket.InputBin property and I have come across a reference to a PageInputBin schema element, but I don't know how to access it.

Alternatively, if anyone can tell me a reliable cross-printer approach for setting booklet mode (2 A4 sides per A3 side folded and saddle & stitched) on the old GDI+ routines then that would be great!